# Filter and MAP Object inside Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

How I can use the filter to populate the variable onlyAmountLess5? I want to filter only products where sales' amount < 5:

```
const products = [
    { id: 1, name: "bread", value: 2.0, category: "bakery", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 12}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 18}] },
    { id: 2, name: "apple", value: 6.5, category: "fruit", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 4}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 18}] },
    { id: 3, name: "pizza", value: 2.0, category: "food", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 5}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 18}]} ,
    { id: 4, name: "cheese", value: 7.0, category: "bakery", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 12}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 5}] },
    { id: 5, name: "milk", value: 2.2, category: "food", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 12}, {"dia": "10/04/2021", "amount": 3}]}
  ];

const onlyBakery = products.filter( p => p.category ==="bakery")
console.log(onlyBakery);

// List only product where sales amount < 5
const onlyAmountLess5 = products.filter(o => products.sales.amount < 4)
```

Comment: But sales is an array right. If even one of the sales from product is less than 5 you want to show it or only if all of them?

Comment: Minor note `< 4` is not the same as `< 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the entry where all the amounts are less than 5, you can use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

**Note** that it would give an empty array, as for none of the example all objects have an amount lesser than 5.

Mind that `< 4` is not the same as `<5`. You could also write `<=4` instead.

```js
const products = [
    { id: 1, name: "bread", value: 2.0, category: "bakery", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 12}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 18}] },
    { id: 2, name: "apple", value: 6.5, category: "fruit", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 4}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 18}] },
    { id: 3, name: "pizza", value: 2.0, category: "food", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 5}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 18}]} ,
    { id: 4, name: "cheese", value: 7.0, category: "bakery", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 12}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 5}] },
    { id: 5, name: "milk", value: 2.2, category: "food", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 12}, {"dia": "10/04/2021", "amount": 3}]}
];
const onlyAmountLess5 = products.filter(o =>o.sales.every(i => i.amount < 5));
console.log(onlyAmountLess5);
```

An example using `< 13` to return 2 entries:

```js
const products = [
    { id: 1, name: "bread", value: 2.0, category: "bakery", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 12}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 18}] },
    { id: 2, name: "apple", value: 6.5, category: "fruit", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 4}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 18}] },
    { id: 3, name: "pizza", value: 2.0, category: "food", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 5}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 18}]} ,
    { id: 4, name: "cheese", value: 7.0, category: "bakery", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 12}, {"day": "10/04/2021", "amount": 5}] },
    { id: 5, name: "milk", value: 2.2, category: "food", "sales":[{"day": "07/04/2021", "amount": 12}, {"dia": "10/04/2021", "amount": 3}]}
];
const onlyAmountLess5 = products.filter(o =>o.sales.every(i => i.amount < 13));
console.log(onlyAmountLess5);
```

Comment: Hi The fourth bird, can you fix this filter? I just add one more element "customers"

`

Comment: @TulioVargas You unselected the mark as answer, but the provided answer is for the related question.

Answer (score 1):

The field sales has two amounts. If you want to check them all you can do it like this:

```js
const maxAmount = 5;
const onlyAmountLess5 = products.filter(product => product.sales.some(item => item.amount < maxAmount));
```

Comment: Thank you Erik.
in case of both amounts must be less than 5, how I could do it?